# Template that uses another template

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I'm coding a toy calendar.
It contains this template meeting type:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Meeting_t
{
    private:
        T startTime;
        T endTime;
        string subject;
    public:
        Meeting_t(){
            //do not delete, a default CTOR will be always created
            //this way we at least know something is wrong
            return NULL;
        }
        ~Meeting_t(){
            //members are all managed outside of the object
        }
        Meeting_t(T sTime, T eTime, string subj){
            startTime = sTime;
            endTime = eTime;
            subject = subj;
        }

        //getters
        inline T GetStartTime() { return startTime; };
        inline T GetEndTime() { return endTime; };
        inline string GetSubject() { return subject; };

        // == implementation
        inline bool operator == (Meeting_t otherMeeting) {
            return GetStartTime() == otherMeeting.GetStartTime();
        };

        inline bool operator < (Meeting_t otherMeeting) {
            return GetStartTime() < otherMeeting.GetStartTime();
        };

        inline bool operator > (Meeting_t otherMeeting) {
            return GetStartTime() > otherMeeting.GetStartTime();
        };

        inline void Print(){
            cout << "\n*** *** ***\n";

            cout << "\nSubject is:\n";
            cout << GetSubject();
            cout << "\nStart time is:\n";
            cout << GetStartTime();
            cout << "\nEnd time is:\n";
            cout << GetEndTime();
            cout << "\n";
        };

};
```

and my calendar skeleton looks like:

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include "Meeting_t.h"

template <typename T>
class DayCalendar_t
{
public:
    //CTORs
    DayCalendar_t(){};

    //DTOR
    //Free all allocated memory allocated for the object
    ~DayCalendar_t(){};

private:
    //fields
    std::map<T, Meeting_t::template Meeting_t* <T>> MeetingMap;
};
```

As you see I chose to use c++ map template, yet it complains about the syntax in the last line:

```
std::map<T, Meeting_t::template Meeting_t* <T>> MeetingMap;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Columbo I guess its the problem yet I fail to find the correct syntax, may you assist me?

Comment: Is the value type supposed to be a pointer?

Comment: @GalB1t what is the type that you intend to be the value type of the map?

Comment: 1. Do not write destructors if you do not need them explicitly. 2. `std::map<T, Meeting_t<T>*> MeetingMap;`

Comment: @user2079303 yes it should hold pointers due to the spec I got

Comment: @Pixelchemist 1 - OK, 2 - Great!

Comment: Please note that the `_t` suffix for types is reserved on POSIX systems, and that you should rather use `std::` than `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @BetaCarotin '_t' is due to specific demand, accepts your advice about 'std'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
std::map<T, Meeting_t<T>*> MeetingMap;
```

And by the way, your default constructor is wrong, as you cannot return a value from it.

You seem to have written this to prevent someone to use the default constructor, but your statement that a default constructor would be generated automatically is wrong since you provided a custom contructor.

Comment: You're 100% right, my intention was that if I won't supply this default CTOR it will be auto-generated "behind the scenes".